# Decoding nested JSON

Tags: swift

I am having trouble decoding the following:

```
struct Categories: Codable {
    var categories: [Category]
}

struct Category: Codable {
    var idCategory: Int
    var strCategory: String
    var strCategoryThumb: String
    var strCategoryDescription: String
}

let url = URL(string: "https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/categories.php")!
let session = URLSession.shared

let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
    if error == nil && data != nil {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
            let allCategories = try decoder.decode(Categories.self, from: data!)
            print(allCategories)
        } catch {
            print("JSON parsing error")
        }
    }
}

dataTask.resume()
```

For some reason the JSON is not decoded/printed and instead only the "JSON parsing error" is printed. What exactly is it thats going wrong in this case?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Print the actual error instead of a hard coded string, `print(error)`

Answer (score 0):

you can print the error description to help you figure out what's wrong with your json
use:

```
print(error.localizedDescription)
```

just after

```
print("JSON parsing error")
```

and idCategory should be String instead of Int type

```
struct Category: Codable {
    var idCategory: String
    var strCategory: String
    var strCategoryThumb: String
    var strCategoryDescription: String
}
```